# How to write Unit Test using Unity Framework for IOC

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, unity-container

Currently I am learning DI and IOC. I have developed small application using unity framework. Now I would like to design/develop Unit Test for the same. Could anyone please help me with it ?

I would like to know how to write a code for this. I have already tried few things but no luck. It is giving me an object reference Error.

Please find my code as below

**Project Code**

```
public interface IDeserialize
{
    List<book> GetDeserialize();
}

public class Deserialize : IDeserialize
{
    private IPathProvider _pathProvider;
    private const string _fileName = "\\XML\\Books.xml";
    private const string _xmlRootAttribute = "Books";

    public Deserialize(IPathProvider pathProvider)
    {
        _pathProvider = pathProvider;
    }

    public List<book> GetDeserialize()
    {    
        string xmlString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(_pathProvider.FilePath(_fileName));

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<book>), new XmlRootAttribute(_xmlRootAttribute));
        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            return (List<book>)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
        }
    }
}
```

**BookListController**

```
  public BookListController(IDeserialize desrializeServiceProvider, ISerialize serializeServiceProvider)
    {
        _deserializeServiceProvider = desrializeServiceProvider;
        _serializeServiceProvider = serializeServiceProvider;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Book Operations
    // GET: BookList
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsValidUser())
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
            }
            else
            {
                List<book> books = _deserializeServiceProvider.GetDeserialize();
            }
        }
        }
```

**IOCconfigurator.cs**

```
 public static class IocConfigurator
{
    public static void ConfigureIocContainer()
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        registerServices(container);

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new LibraryDependencyResolver(container));
    }

    private static void registerServices(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<IDeserialize, Deserialize>();
        container.RegisterType<ISerialize, Serialize>();
        container.RegisterType<IPathProvider, PathProvider>();
    }
}
```

**Unit Test Code** - Which is not working

```
[TestClass]
public class BookListControllerTest
{
    private IPathProvider TestPathProvider()
    {
        Mock<IPathProvider> mockObject = new Mock<IPathProvider>();
        mockObject.Setup(m => m.FilePath("\\XML\\Books.xml"));
        return mockObject.Object;
    }

    // Step 6. Add the definition of the mock objects
    private IDeserialize TestDeserialize()
    {
        IPathProvider pp = this.TestPathProvider();

        Mock<IDeserialize> mockObject = new Mock<IDeserialize>();
        Deserialize dc = new Deserialize(pp);
        mockObject.Setup(m => m.GetDeserialize());
        return mockObject.Object;
    }

    private ISerialize TestSerialize()
    {
        IPathProvider pp = this.TestPathProvider();
        Mock<ISerialize> mockObject = new Mock<ISerialize>();
        Serialize sc = new Serialize(pp);
        List<book> books = null;
        mockObject.Setup(m => m.GetSerialize(books));
        return mockObject.Object;
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void Index()
    {

        IDeserialize ds = this.TestDeserialize();
        ISerialize sd = this.TestSerialize();

        BookListController controller = new BookListController(ds, sd);

        ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        Assert.IsNotNull(result.Model);
    }
```

Let me know if you need any other Information.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] including the source code of `BookListController`.

Comment: @mjwills It is giving me error at _deserializeServiceProvider.GetDeserialize();

Comment: https://github.com/moq/moq4

Comment: On the `BookListController controller = new BookListController(ds, sd);` line, what is the value of `ds.GetType()`? `sd.GetType()`? _Please check both with the `Immediate Window`._

Comment: ds.GetType()
{Name = "IDeserializeProxy" FullName = "Castle.Proxies.IDeserializeProxy"}
    Assembly: {DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}
    AssemblyQualifiedName: "Castle.Proxies.IDeserializeProxy, DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    Attributes: Public | Serializable
    BaseType: {Name = "InterfaceProxy" FullName = "Moq.Internals.InterfaceProxy"}
    ContainsGenericParameters: false
    CustomAttributes: Count = 2
    DeclaredConstructors: {System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo[2]}

Comment: For one, don't involve Unity in anyway in your unit testing.  Its an unnecessary dependency that makes writing unit tests harder.

Comment: @Andy All I want to achieve is to write unit test... Could you please help me to write unit test for my project code ?

Comment: That's not quite what this site is for.  Not using Unity will make it easier for you to write your tests though, which is why I commented about it.